# About route (link) and asynchronous fetch data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

First of all, good evening. I'm trying to improve myself at React. So I'm working on a Starwars project ‍.

I have two problems.
First of all, I listed different characters at the bottom of my character detail page. Again, I want it to be directed to different characters through the same component. But even if the link changes, my component is not refreshed, but the picture is changing .

Note:
sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app/

my project github link : https://github.com/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app/

First problem improper route and link.

```
// component that I redirect in.

class CharacterDetail extends Component {

  render () {
    const characterId = this.props.match.params.id;
    const {
      name,
      height,
      mass,
      hair_color,
      skin_color,
      eye_color,
      birthday_year,
      gender,
      homeworld,
      loading,
    } = this.state;
    return loading
      ? <Loading />
      : (
        <div>
          <main className="characterBg">
            <DetailHeader imgLink={characterAvatarLink[characterId - 1]} />
            <CharacterContent
              imgLink={characterAvatarLink[characterId- 1]}
              characterInfo={this.state}
            />
          </main>
          <FeaturedCharacters />
        </div>
      );
  }
}

// featured character component 
function FeaturedCharacters () {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState ([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState (true);

  const fetchCharacters = async () => {
    const data = await fetch ('https://swapi.co/api/people/');
    const fetchPeople = await data.json ();
    const feauteredCharacter = fetchPeople.results.filter (
      (character, index) => index < 4
    );
    setCharacters (feauteredCharacter);
    setLoading (false);
  };
  useEffect (() => {
    fetchCharacters ();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Popular Characters</h2>
      <div className="d-flex-row container">
        {loading
          ? <PlaceholderDiv />
          : characters.map ((character, index) => (
            <CharacterCard
              key={character.name}
              chaId={index + 1}
              chaDet={character.name}
              imgLink={characterAvatarLink[index]}
            />
            ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// character card link component
const CharacterCard = props => {
  const name = props.chaDet;
  return (
    <Link className="profile_card" to={`/character/${props.chaId}`}>
      <div className="profile_image">
        <img src={props.imgLink} alt={name} />
      </div>
      <div className="profile_content">
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <div className="read_more d-flex-row">
          <img src={showIcon} alt="Show Icon" />
          &nbsp;Show More
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};



// main component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="st-container d-flex-column">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/movie/:title" component={MovieDetails} />
          <Route path="/character/:id" component={CharacterDetail} />
          <Route
            path="/githubProfile"
            component={() => {
              window.location.href = 'https://github.com/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app';
              return null;
            }}
          />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

---

My second problem is that I draw a data back from the data from API. I can reach outlines of the character. It's working now. But I feel that there are some things that don't feel right. How can I improve Fetch operations in Axios?

The component I fetch from API:

```
  async componentDidMount () {
    const characterId = this.props.match.params.id;
    const filmSeries = [];
    const characterDetail = await axios.get (
      `https://swapi.co/api/people/${characterId}/`
    );


    const filmsFetchLinks = characterDetail.data.films;

    const promisesData = await filmsFetchLinks.map(link => axios.get(link));
    axios.all (promisesData).then(value => {
      value.map (val => filmSeries.push (val.data.title));
      let {
        name,
        height,
        mass,
        hair_color,
        skin_color,
        eye_color,
        birthday_year,
        gender,
        homeworld,
        films,
      } = characterDetail.data;

      fetch(homeworld).then(home => home.json()).then(val => this.setState({homeworld: val.name}));


      this.setState ({
        name,
        height,
        mass,
        hair_color,
        skin_color,
        eye_color,
        birthday_year,
        gender,
        films: filmSeries,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm sorry if I bored you. It seems a little long because the components are interconnected.

Comment: Could you kindly put the SWAPI app on codesanbox?  Also, as a side note, you usually don't want to check in `.env` files.

Comment: sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app/

Comment: When I threw it into the Sandbox, I noticed that the mobile look was bad. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` and compare the the current parameter id to the previous one (you would have to save it to state) and you fetch data again IFF the two are different.  `componentDidUpdate` will go every time the route changes.

A better approach would be to use `useEffect` and depend on the parameter id.  In the use effect, you do all your data fetching.  Something like this:

```
 const { id: characterId } = props.match.params;

 React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
       // fetch all you data here
    }
    getData();
  }, [characterId]);
```

You can see a crude version of this here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/star-wars-app-sx8hk

Comment: it's weird that it doesn't work when you do this with ComponentDidMount. Sorry for the late recycling. thank you. do you think I can make my project more clean as code?

Comment: What has helped me write "cleaner" code is having linting rules in place.  I can't even commit code unless it passes linting rules.  For formatting, I use prettier.  Both of these things make a difference.